# should I commit in the following code?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi, dbd-pg

My code:

```
122 #
123 my $hfpDbh = undef;
124 unless (
125         $hfpDbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:host=....")#removed something
128 ) {
129         Log( ERROR, "" );
130         Exit( 1 )
131 }
132 $hfpDbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
133 $hfpDbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
134 
135 ( my $mydata, $msg ) = load_data( $hfpDbh, $DatFile );
136 unless ( defined($mydata) )
137 {
138         Log(INFO, "Calling exit...2");
139 }
140 #$hfpDbh->disconnect();
141 Exit( 0 );
142 Log(INFO, "Calling exit...4");
143 
144 
145 sub load_data
146 {
147         my ( $dbh, $DatFile ) = @_;
148         my $msg = '';
149         unless ( $dbh ) {
150                 $msg = 'cannot load data, no DB handle';
151                 Log( ERROR, $msg );
152         }
153         Log(INFO, "Call load_data...");
154         my $q = "SELECT ip as ip FROM rules WHERE active = 'true' AND isGood = 'true';";
155         my $stmt = undef;
156         unless ( $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $q ) ) {
157                 $msg = "unable to prepare SQL query: $q";
158                 Log( ERROR, $msg );
159         }
160 
161         eval { $stmt->execute() };
162         if ( $@ ) {
163                 $msg = "failed to execute SQL query: $@";
164                 Log( ERROR, $msg );
165         }
166 
167         my $data = {};
168         while ( my $row = $stmt->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
169                 #Log(INFO, "testing row");
170         }
171         $stmt->finish();
172         return $data, $msg;
173 }
```

The warning is:

```
Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect() of DBD::Pg::db handle
```

If I add "$dbh->commit()" after Line 171, the above warn disappeared.

If I did not add "$dbh->commit()" after Line 171 but called "$hfpDbh->disconnect();" in Line 140, the above warn disappeared too.

My question is:
**The warning means that there are uncommitted transactions? That is why I need to commit or disconnect explicitly to fix the warning. But there is only SELECT operation in the code. What I am missing?**

Thanks.

Comment: Your error handling is a little wonky. You're already enabling `RaiseError`, so you shouldn't be checking the success of every method by hand. `RaiseError` will throw an exception if there's an error. If you want to use a custom error handler (for example, to log errors), use [`HandleError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#HandleError).

Comment: @ikegami but disconnect() will do rollback on uncommitted transactions? AM I right? If I did not call load_data() function, the warning will disappear even if I did not disconnect.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't call `finish`, and you should make sure `disconnect` is called even when there's an exception or signal (e.g. with an `END` block and a signal handler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since you aren't modifying the database at all, you don't need to enable transactions, so don't set `AutoCommit` to zero. That way there's no need to call `commit` anywhere either, and the database will be disconnected automatically when the handle goes out of dcope
- Since you're handling errors yourself you shouldn't set `RaiseError` to 1. That will cause your program to die immediately if any error occurs and your own handling code won't get executed
- There's no need to call `finish`. It won't do any harm here, but it's also pointless and should almost never be necessary

Comment: If AutoCommit set to zero, transactions will be enabled? and I need to call commit or rollback after SELECT?

Comment: @BAE: Yes, setting `AutoCommit` to zero enables transactions. But you aren't modifying the database so you don't need them. With transactions disabled you need neither `commit` nor `rollback` anywhere

Answer (score 2):

> *The warning means that there are uncommitted transactions?*

There is an uncommitted transaction since you requested for transactions to be used, but the warning actually notifies you that a rollback was performed implicitly. It tells you this because this may result in a loss of information. Obviously, it won't result in a loss of information in this case, but the check isn't smart enough of realize this.

> *What I am missing?*

`$hfpDbh->disconnect();` or `$hfpDbh->rollback();`

Comment: If I did not call load_data() function, the warning will disappear even if I did not disconnect. So I guess there may be uncommitted transactions or something else, for which I need to call commit or disconnect explicitly... But I am confused.

Comment: It must realize there's no need to call `rollback` in that situation, so it doesn't.

Comment: I remember that in python psql client, commit() should be called even if only select is done.

Comment: @ikegami If there are no uncommitted transactions, why rollback was performed implicitly?

Comment: @ikegami Thanks. the select query? how can I know which transaction is it?